# Is there a way to connect a PICO-W or any ESP32 using Python code to connect to a network with WPS?

Tags: python, wifi, wps

Is there a way to connect a PICO-W or any ESP32 using Python code to connect to a network with WPS?

I have created some IoT modules for me, very useful but just for me at this moment.

I want to give some modules to my parents and my friends.

I don't know which Wifi network they use. Themselves do not know their login credentials (i.e. the password is very large)!

So, best way is to connect their Wifi is to use WPS button.

I do not find any code in Python to connect with WPS.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It's dificult to provide any code when I'm writing "I do not find any code in Python to connect with WPS"...

I can try to explain more :
a) I want to create an PICO-W (or ESP32) module connected on wifi
b) Wifi credentials (login/password) are not known and cannot be set in the code because we don't know the final user of the module
c) The module have a "search wifi" button in order to connect Wifi using WPS (user have to push the button on his Internet-Box or routeur). WPS is a very known standard.

Thanks in advance for your help